# Reordering items in a dynamic collection / list stored in Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-redux

I'm currently making an interface to construct a questionnaire. Each question within the questionnaire is stored in Firebase with the following structure:

```
questions
   | - {key}
         | - lastModified // <-- When the question was created, last updated
         | - position // <-- The position in which the question appears on frontend
         | - question // <-- Question text content
         | - uid // <-- The unique key with which it is saved to firebase

   /* ... */
   /* Repeat for n questions! */
   /* ... */
```

The admin can add, remove, update and reorder questions.

When an admin **removes** a question, I have to increment the position value of all questions underneath the removed question.

The way I am approaching this is to modify my locally stored copy of the list (in my case, cloning the array stored in Redux state), performing necessary adjustments and then pushing it to firebase overriding the existing 'questions' data set.

Here is my code:

```
// Remove question action creator
export function removeQuestion(key, questions) {

  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: REMOVE_QUESTION});

    const updatedQuestions = questions.filter((question) => {
      return !(question.uid === key); // I remove the target item here.
    }).map((question, index) => {
      return {
        lastModified: question.lastModified,
        position: index, // I update the position of all other items here.
        question: question.question,
        stageId: question.stageId,
        uid: question.uid
      };
    });

    questionsRef.set(updatedQuestions) // And then I save the entire updated dataset here.
    .then(() => dispatch(removeQuestionSuccess(key)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(removeQuestionError(key, error)));
  };
}
```

**But, is there a better way of doing this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I've opted for. What I've done is:

- No longer store list of as an array locally (in my case in Redux state), store it as an object as pulled from Firebase, convert it to an array whenever it needs to be mutated.
- Working with the array, remove specified item (I used [Array.Filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this)
- Map over array, updating each item with their new position (using map index)
- Parse array back into an object before pushing it back to Firebase

---

This is a generalised version of the code I've written so it might be applied to any list of items:

```
export function removeItem(key, items) {
  return (dispatch) => {

    dispatch({type: REMOVE_ITEM});

    // Convert items object (from state) into an array for easier manipulation
    const itemsArr = items ? Object.keys(items).map(key => items[key]) : [];

    const updatedItems = itemsArr.filter((item) => {
      // Filter out the item that needs to be removed
      return !(item.uid === key);
    }).map((item, index) => {
      // Update new position for remaining items
      return {
        lastModified: item.lastModified,
        position: index,
        content: item.content,
        uid: item.uid
      };
    });

    // Parsing array back into obj before pushing to Firebase
    let updatedItemsObj = {};
    updatedItems.forEach(item => {
      updatedItemsObj[item.uid] = item;
    });
    itemsRef.set(updatedItemsObj)
    .then(() => dispatch(nextAction(...)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(errorAction(key, error)));
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can solve this is to use a floating point number to represent the position instead of an actual ordinal integer. Then, when you need to re-order, rather than re-saving all of the various positions, simply take the midpoint between the two items you're moving between.

This way, when you remove an item, you can just leave the other values alone because `position` is ordered but not ordinal.

An example (items are letters, positions are numbers):

```
A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4

-> move D between A and B

A: 1, D: 1.5, B: 2, C: 3

-> move C between D and B

A: 1, D: 1.5, C: 1.75, B: 2

-> remove D

A: 1, C: 1.75, B: 2
```

Comment: This certainly would make maintaining position simpler following item repositioning or removal. Thanks for the suggestion. 

I've seen this before, though instead of using an float, using an ordinal number, but to the magnitude of 100 or 10 (eg. A: 10, B: 20, C: 30).

I see now the advantage of the float is that the midpoint can always be calculated, the difference between adjacent positioned items can become smaller and smaller fractions. But does it ever break? I suppose it depends on how you handle floating point precision on your end?

Comment: There's some theoretical limit / number of reorderings where it'll break, but it would require a huge number of worst-case reorderings to do so (I think). You could have some kind of "reset" that re-ordinalizes them if it hits some threshold (e.g. if the siblings are < 0.00001 apart or something).